# Bullet-proofing tags with punctuation

Tags: templating, tags, routes

I have a route set up with a tag:
news/tag/[tag] => news/_tag

How do I generate urls that will match that route for all possible tags (including tags with punctuation)?

How do I resolve that url back to a tag (including tags with punctuation)?

Note that twigs [url_encode](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/url_encode.html) filter `href="{{tag.name|url_encode}}"` will generate urls that don't route to the template for some tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To generate the url, use the [slugify](https://gist.github.com/boboldehampsink/7354431/download#) plugin: `href="{{tag.name|slugify}}"`. Slugify uses Craft's slug technology, so the slugs are always recognized by the router.

To resolve the url back to a tag, use `search` in the `news/_tag` template:

```twig
{% set thisTag = craft.tags.search('name:"'~tag~'"').first() %}
```

`craft.tags.name(tag).first()` will often work, but not for all slugs, so this is also possible, and may be more efficient if that is an issue:

```
{% set thisTag = craft.tags.name(tag).first() %}
{% if not thisTag %} {% set thisTag = craft.tags.search('name:"'~tag~'"').first() %} {% endif %}
```